# SQL Server pivot up to 10 columns, if more then automatically fill in the next row

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table with many rows of data
I want it to turn into a table with 10 columns of data

This is a multi-line data table:

```
SELECT T.*
INTO #Temps
FROM
(SELECT 
'A' AS CloGroup,    1 AS ColNumber UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    2 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    3 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    4 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    5 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    6 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    7 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    8 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    9 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    10 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    11 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    12 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    13 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    14 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    15 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    16 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    17 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    18 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    19 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    20 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    21 UNION ALL SELECT
'A',    22 UNION ALL SELECT
'B',    30 UNION ALL SELECT
'B',    31 UNION ALL SELECT
'B',    32 UNION ALL SELECT
'B',    33 UNION ALL SELECT
'B',    34 UNION ALL SELECT
'B',    35 UNION ALL SELECT
'B',    30 UNION ALL SELECT
'B',    31 UNION ALL SELECT
'B',    32 UNION ALL SELECT
'B',    33 UNION ALL SELECT
'B',    40 UNION ALL SELECT
'B',    41 UNION ALL SELECT
'B',    42 UNION ALL SELECT
'B',    43 UNION ALL SELECT
'B',    40) T

SELECT #Temps.* FROM #Temps

DROP TABLE #Temps
```

**I want do to switch to 10 columns like this**

Group-Col1--Col2--Col3--Col4--Col5--Col6--Col7--Col8--Col9--Col10

A-----1-----2-----3-----4-----5-----6-----7-----8-----9-----10

A-----11----12----13----14----15----16----17----18----19----20

B-----30----31----32----33----34----35----30----31----32----33

B-----40----41----42----43----40

This is the resulting figure I want (image)

[The result I want is like the picture on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP9v7.png)

Comment: All content on [so] needs to be in English; what does that hyperlink state?

Comment: You also haven't asked a question here, just dumped some data and a requirement with *no expected results*. What are you asking? What is the difficulty *you* are having achieving your goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT  CloGroup, [0] AS Column1, [1] AS Column2, [2] AS Column3, [3] AS Column4,[4] AS Column5,[5] AS Column6,[6] AS Column7,[7] AS Column8,[8] AS Column9,[9] AS Column10
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
        SELECT  (colnumber-1) % 10 AS colid
        ,   (colnumber -1) / 10 AS colid2
        ,   *
        FROM    #Temps c
        ) x
    PIVOT(MAX(ColNumber) FOR colid IN ([0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])) x
    ) x
```

The extra column colid2 creates a grouping which generates new row every 10 rows, by wrapping it in subselect you can remove it if you don't need it

Comment: Thanks for your support. 
The result is still not what I want.
I want it to look like this.  [The picture depicts the result I want](https://ibb.co/q9Mk8SQ)

Comment: That's not really possible unless you also have an order column which sorts A,B